# Обращение к потомку через родителя

Tags: delphi, компоненты

Я динамически создаю панель. На панели, так же динамически — label.

```
myPanel:= TPanel.Create( ScrollBox1 );
myPanel.Parent:= ScrollBox1;
myPanel.Width:= 409;
myPanel.Height:= 89;
myPanel.Left:= 16;
myPanel.Top:= buttonLoad.Tag;
myPanel.OnClick:= PanelClick;

myLabel1:= TLabel.Create( myPanel );
myLabel1.Parent:= myPanel;
myLabel1.Top:= 13;
myLabel1.Left:= 40;
myLabel1.Caption:= myString3;
myLabel1.Name:= 'myLabel1';
```

Панели я присваиваю обработчик при клике.
И теперь, вопрос: Как мне, имея **Sender** компонента родителя, ( **myPanel** ) получить доступ к компоненту потомку? ( **myLabel1** )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно просмотреть все компоненты, прикрепленные к панели:

```
  // код пишу по памяти :)
  // просматриваем все компоненты
  for h := 1 to TPanel(Sender).ComponentCount - 1 do
    // Если это лейбл, смотрим тег
    if TPanel(Sender).Components[h].ClassType = TLabel then
       // Если тег такой, какой нужен, меняем капшн
       if TLabel(TPanel(Sender).Components[h]).Tag = 1 then
          TLabel(TPanel(Sender).Components[h]).Caption:= "123";
```

Разумеется в этом случае у каждого объекта, расположенного на панели должен быть какой-либо уникальный идентификатор, чтобы вы могли обратиться к нужному.

Comment: У каждого компонента уникальное имя ( в пределах одной панели )
Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: Да не за что)